# Angular autocomplete options don't keep position with input

Tags: html, css, angular, sass, angular-material

There is showcase my issue. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-efmp9q-aztprs I have a scrollable div, which have a specific height. In this div i have an angular material autocomplete component. When i select input for autocomplete, i get an offer options, but if i scrolling down, mat-option offer don't keep of input. But is moving with scrolling. Is possible in this case to keep position with input ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem before and at that moment I found a solution, you need to import scrolling module from angular/material and use the directive `cdkScrollable` in your outermost div.

In your stackblitz example you already imported the scrolling module, hence you only need to add `cdkScrollable` to the div which has the wrapper class:

```html
<div class="wrapper" cdkScrollable>
```